# Best way to compel a user to update (Mobile Application)

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I have being thinking of a way to implement a system that will force a User to update an Application just like what `WhatsApp` is currently doing.

`This is what I want to achieve...`
In the case of `WhatsApp`, you are being informed when the Application starts within the giving time that the Application will expire in an amount of days, that the user should update before the current Apps expires. If the giving date expires, the Application will start but you can't access your messages.

`This is what I am thinking so far..`
I am thinking of implementing this scenario using SQLite, that is, the Apps will contact the Server twice a week to check if there is a new version by comparing the version number at the Server to the one stored in an SQLite Database in the phone. If the Apps is outdated, a count down should initialize and intend using the phone local time to initiate this and when the given days are exhausted, the Apps will refuse to show the main page of the Apps.

`Potential problem of the proposed system`
Since I am thinking of using the phone local time, I foresee a problem where the user of the Apps intentionally wipe the `cache` of the Apps, this means the count down will have to restart counting. To be able to circumvent this problem, I thought of using an encrypted file to store the amount of days remaining and with this, even if the countdown is re-intialized, it will fallback to the days remaining in the encrypted file.

Note: Am using PhoneGap for my Apps.

This is what I am thinking, I don't know if there are better ideas on achieving this out there, please, if you have a better idea on how to achieve this, please do share with me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what happens on a user's device. Moreover, it's bad idea in general. Any cache, any database, any file could be wiped. So there is no concrete answer, it depends on the initial reason of such update policy:

1. Your app just can't work if it is outdated. For instance because of you updated backed API and you don't want to support several versions of API. Then just always(every launching of the app) compare versions. If device is connected to the internet and there's no information about last version on a device then just say it to user: `App will not work until you update if`
2. If your app can work but it's not desirable then I recommend you to give user right to decide update his app or not.

Comment: I want a situation just like what `WhatApps` is using, when new features are released, I want the Users to update and make use of it but they will be given a prior notice of at least 2 weeks. The best possible way of implementing this is what I want opinions about.